# Can I import a file from local drive to VMWare HDP 2.5 Sandbox to use in Spark through Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, vmware, apache-zeppelin, hortonworks-sandbox

I want to use local text files in my Spark program which I am running in HDP 2.5 Sandbox in VMWare.

1) Is there any drag and drop way to directly get it in the HDFS of the VM?

2) Can I import it using Zeppelin? If yes, then how to get the absolute path (location) to use it in Spark?

3) Any other way? What and how, if yes?

Comment: To get files from your host to the VM, you need to use SCP or (S)FTP

Answer (score 0):

To get data into HDFS within your VM, you will need to use the `hdfs` command to push the files from local file system within your VM into HDFS within the VM.  The command should look something like:

```
hadoop fs -put filename.log /my/hdfs/path
```

For more information on HDFS commands, please refer to [Hadoop File System Shell Commands](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html).

Saying this, as you are using Apache Spark, you can also refer to the local file system instead of HDFS.  To do this, you would use the `file:///...` instead of `hdfs://...`.  For example, to access a file within HDFS via Spark, you can usually run a command like:

```
val mobiletxt = sc.textFile("/data/filename.txt")
```

but you can also access the VM's local file system like:

```
val mobiletxt = sc.textFile("file:///home/user/data/filename.txt")
```

As for Apache Zeppelin, this is a notebook interface to work with Apache Spark (and other systems); there current is no import mechanism within Zeppelin itself.  Instead, you will do something like above within your notebook to access either the VM's HDFS or local file system.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but how will I import the file from the desktop to the VM's local file system?

Comment: If you're using VirtualBox, you can reference: https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/09/copy-paste-virtualbox-host-guest-machines/.  If you're using VMWare, you can reference: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_dragndrop.html.  HTH!